# How to apply separate conditional formatting rules for different Pivot Table Row Lable sections

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that has two sections, a High Priority and Normal Priority section that needs different sets of conditional formatting rules, due to the High Priority section having higher standards etc. Is there a way to do this? So far I have only been able to apply rules to every row, not distinguishing between High and Normal priority. The attached table is a sample of how the table is structured. For example, I need to have one rule that fills red if the High Priority groups are under 7, and a rule that fills red if the Normal Priority groups are under 6. [Sample Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLg76.png)

Comment: seems like you need to build your conditional fomatting using the `GETPIVOTDATA()` formula